# Starting packager stuck after npm audit & component folder doesn't work

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo

**Hi all,**

First of all, I know that this is possibly a duplicate of many other posts, but I've already tried all things people posted on stack/github.

I have two problems:

1. After running `npm audit fix` packager will be stuck at `starting packager...`
2. I have a component folder with three components in it, but when I run the project it says that the components don't exist.

The first problem isn't really that bad to me, I can just ignore running `npm audit`.

The second problem, however, does annoy me.
This is my folder structure:
[image]

My IDE says everything is OK. My IDE automatically imported the components from my component folder and it links to them, correctly.

But I get this error:

```
9:40:04 AM: Unable to resolve ./components/Home" from ".//App.js`: The module `./components/Home` could not be found"
9:40:04 AM: Failed building JavaScript bundle
```

I hope someone can help me because I don't know where to start or what to do.

My setup:
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Testing device: Android
Testing with: Expo (create-react-native-app)

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: I'm curious why Metro is printing `.//App.js` for the entry point, perhaps something is weird with the paths its picking up? Could you try restarting your computer and pasting the contents of app.json and package.json?

Comment: @dikaiosune thanks for responding. I don't know what it is, I'm lost pretty much. Here is my [app.json](https://pastebin.com/GTT4k788), and here is my [package.json](https://pastebin.com/nqWc6Fvj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the second issue, using `.jsx` extensions in `create-react-native-app` isn't supported. You can just use the `.js` extension and still use jsx, though.

So to fix your problem, rename all the `.jsx` files to just `.js`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That fixed problem two for me. Is there any chance you know why `npm audit fix` doesn't work?

Comment: Could you give me a list of all the packages `npm audit fix` updates?